# Punch state automatically changes its status on ZK devices

Tags: sdk, checkout, fingerprint, checkin, time-and-attendance

I want to change punch state automatically much like as when user first comes in it will say check-in and when it comes second time it will say it as checkout and so on. I want punch state switching based on every user which comes in and out at any time.I am using ZK MB360 device for fingerprints.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported by any zk fingerprint devices. you need to handle this case in your software while you receive the attendance data.